# HP Compaq LA2306x displayport

Tags: displayport

i have HP Compaq LA2306x monitor. It has `displayport` socket on it.
And i read that `displayport` can transport sound too.
Is this means my monitor has speaker on it?
I was googling it but still don't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

According to the specs here, it does not have built-in speakers. http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824176205

[image: Partial specifications]

Comment: You should quote the specifications.  You can use a screenshot, and use the tool snipping tool, to accomplish that. The Connectivity section, the lack of an audio port, proves your statement.